# Pi3b power draw with ethernet and HDMI

Tags: pi-3, power

Does anyone know what would be the max draw (With no peripherals attached) of Pi3b board when using ethernet and HDMI? WiFi and Bluetooth would be turned off.

I would like to know if its reliable long term to power the board from 5V 0.5A (USB2 outlet) or 5V 0.9A (USB3 outlet).

My situation is: I would like to power the Pi from USB outlet of TV.

Comment: @Milliways has already provided a good answer, but I'll just add that I highly doubt your TV will output enough power for the RPi to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Many people have powered Pi3 from limited PS, but it is not recommended See [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations)

It may or may **NOT** work, depending on the USB source. Strictly, a compliant source will only supply 100mA without negotiation. My Mac is an example of a compliant source.

The Pi **cannot** negotiate, because it has no data lines.

Many non-compliant sources actually deliver unlimited current, and may work.

Answer (score 1):

There's more information in the [Raspberry Pi FAQs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#powerReqs) on powering a Raspberry Pi 3 B:

- Bare-board consumption: ~400mA
- Minimum Recommended: 1.2A
- Maximum USB power draw: 1.2A
- Recommended: 2.5A (=minimum recommended + maximum USB power draw)

Going further into the FAQs we see more useful numbers for the Pi 3 based on average & peak consumption. Peaks: 0,75A when booting, 0,55A for video  playback (H2.64) and 1,34A under stress.

I'd say that if you are able to boot the device, you'll be able to do video playback. You won't break the Raspberry Pi 3 by testing this, worst case scenario is that it won't (fully) boot or shuts down.

Give it a try on your USB 3.0 port. Let us know what happens!